# Separate grounds but connected supply voltage between circuits

Tags: safety, grounding

I have a question: For a project I want to separate two circuits for safety reasons. One circuit is a battery powered (+9V) amplifier/level shifter for an electrode touched by the user.

The second circuit is a stationary input module in a separate housing to further process the signals. This other device is powered by mains voltage but runs on a lower symmetric supply voltage.

Therefor I want to separate the two circuits, so there is no return path for current in case the stationary device has a fault. I looked into optocouplers to separate the grounds but I would still power the circuitry after the optocoupler from the same battery as the circuitry before the optocoupler.

This way the grounds between the electrode-processing circuit and the amplifier which connects to the stationary device via 2-wire cable (GND and signal) are separated. But the power supply of the optocoupler's phototransistor is coming of the battery as well.

I wonder if this increases safety at all then or if there is anything I overlook. Thank you!

Here is a simplified drawing to clarify things:
[image]

Comment: You can't 'power the circuitry after the optocoupler from the same battery as the circuitry before the optocoupler' unless the 2 sides share a common ground. Remember that current flows in a loop - then try to figure out how current is going to flow from the battery, through the output side of the opto (pins 3 & 4) and get back to the battery ...

Comment: Thank you @brhans. I got confused earlier than thinking about the current loop and so it made sense that the current would flow into the other ground but that is silly of course. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You won’t get a linear voltage through the opto either.

Comment: Can you please clarify @andy

Comment: What’s the clarification needed?

Comment: Your comment is no answer to my question and it doesn't add information that could help me answer it. So I was thinking if you used more words I could understand what you mean with your comment. That's what the clarification is needed for.

Comment: My comment isn’t an answer and you should therefore take that hint and try and look up or google how you transmit a linear signal across an opto coupler. Instead, you badger me into giving more information when in fact I’m doing you a favour of letting you know what the next problem might be when you come to an implementation. Go google.

Answer (score 0):

No, this won't work. You can't provide voltage to the collector of the optocoupler and not provide a return path to GNDPWR for that current.

You should connect the collector to the op amp's V+ with a suitable series resistor to limit the current.

Comment: You are right, thank you. I won't be able to use the opamp's supply on the mobile device, so I'll have to think about a different solution.

Comment: You haven't provided much information, but a transformer might work if you don't care about dc levels.

Comment: I can't use a transformer because I use a DC signal on the output. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Move the optocoupler into the fixed equipment, and you can use the opamp supply on its output.